# Why does error LNK1104: cannot open file 'xx.lib' occur when compile c project in Visual Studio?

Tags: linker

I am trying to run a packet capture program.

I have downloaded winpcap and have set up a project in visual studio.
However, I am getting an error saying that xx.lib is not found. My friend doesn't get the error with the same setup.

I wondered if the xx.lib file didn't exist on my computer, so I searched for it, but the xx.lib file doesn't exist anywhere on my computer.

Did I install something wrong and the xx.lib file is missing and that's why I'm getting the error?

I just uninstalled and reinstalled Visual Studio and I get the same error.

The github address of the program I want to run is below.
https://github.com/gusdnr9875/Network-Packet-Analysis-Using-Wincap

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVRbO.png)

My guess is that the problem is that the xx.lib file is missing